# Nine neighbors in a hotel

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Alessandra, Marta, Cristiane, Camila, Eduardo, Janice, Giulia, Mateus and Lucas are neighbors who live in a hotel.

- On each floor there are three bedrooms: one on the left, one in the center and one on the right.
- Mateus does not live on the lower floor.
- Janice lives directly above Lucas and directly beside Marta, who lives on the left.
- Eduardo lives on the right and one floor higher than Janice.
- Camila lives directly above Janice.
- Giulia lives directly above Cristiane.
- On no floor only girls live.

Knowing that everyone lives in a room, **who lives on the second floor?**

a. Alessandra, Lucas and Cristiane.
b. Janice, Giulia and Lucas.
c. Marta, Eduardo and Giulia.
d. Alessandra, Marta and Mateus.
e. Eduardo, Lucas and Marta.

No alternative seems to produce a result consistent with the statement. Since, for example, Janice and Marta live on the same floor.

Girls: Alessandra, Marta, Cristiane, Camila, Janice and Giulia.
Boys: Eduardo, Mateus and Lucas.

[Source](https://www.amazon.com.br/Discrete-Mathematics-Its-Applications-English-ebook/dp/B07FF9DY66/ref=asc_df_B07FF9DY66/?tag=googleshopp00-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=405555086537&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15269226543979755276&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1001541&hvtargid=pla-890492241038&psc=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite [Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor) already having posted [a very nice answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106202/29154), I thought I might provide some *super high quality* MSPaint diagrams, as well as an alternative method.
*(Hints are dropped throughout the answer in the form of which clues to use first)*

> On each floor there are three bedrooms: one on the left, one in the center and one on the right.

[image: Base image of the 3 floors]

First we'll deal with these two clues:

> - Janice lives directly above Lucas and directly beside Marta, who lives on the left.
> - Eduardo lives on the right and one floor higher than Janice.

> Janice must live on the 2nd floor or above, since on the first floor she would be above no-one. This means Eduardo must live on the top floor, on the right.
> This in turn means that Janice must live on the 2nd floor, which means Marta must be on the second floor as well (to the left).
>  [image: Eduardo and Janice]

Next we will deal with this clue:

> - Camila lives directly above Janice.

> Camila must live on the 3rd floor, since she is above Janice, who is on the 2nd floor.
> Camila cannot live where Eduardo is, nor can she live on the left, otherwise she would be above Marta and not Janice. Therefore Camila and Janice live on the centre rooms, in their respective floors.
> Additionally, Lucas lives underneath Janice, which means he must live on the centre bottom room.
>  [image: Camila, Janice and Lucas]

Now we can deal with this:

> - On no floor only girls live.

> Very simple given our diagram - we see that the second floor has 1 empty space and no boys! Therefore Mateus (our only remaining boy) must go there.
>  [image: Mateus]

At this point we can stop, since we already have the answer:

> Marta, Janice, and Mateus (left, centre, and right respectively)

However we can finish the puzzle, using our last clue, so why stop there?

> - Giulia lives directly above Cristiane.

> Since there are only 2 remaining spaces which are vertically over each other, we know Giulia and Cristiane must go there, with Giulia at the top floor and Cristiane on the bottom floor.
> This leaves only one last space for Alessandra!
>  [image: Giulia, Cristiane and Alessandra]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will probably stay with the "less wrong".

Comment: This is a great answer, I love the diagrams. +1

Comment: But then Giulia is not directly above Christiane, right? (Since there is one room in between.)

Comment: @Philip I assumed the puzzle had a complete answer, and so that there was some mistranslation where "directly" was used. (Not a great way to go about solving it but I thought it seemed plausible from context)

Comment: @Helen Yes, that’s probably it. Otherwise there would be no solution. (Other then the names might misguide to the gender of the people. :) )

Answer (score 5):

1. > "On no floor only girls live" - so each of the three boys (Eduardo, Mateus, Lucas) must be on a different floor. Mateus isn't on the lower floor, and Eduardo is above Janice, so **Lucas is on the lower floor**.
2. > That means **Janice is on the second floor** and in the middle since she's next to **Marta** who's now **on the left of the second floor**.
3. > Eduardo is above Janice, so the boy on the second floor must be **Mateus**.

Now we know who's living on the second floor, even without solving the rest of the puzzle:

> Marta (left), Janice (middle), Mateus (right).

But then

> Giulia living directly above Cristiane is a contradiction.

It seems there is a problem in the book where you found this! The problem is ill-posed.

Comment: Argh so quick! You got me in the middle of writing an answer

Comment: Also as for the contradiction, only if you assume "directly" means "on the floor above, in the same room". I'm thinking it might mean just "on the same room"